# How to replace a decimal in a number with a string?

Tags: javascript, string, replace, numbers, decimal-point

How can I replace a decimal in a number with a string? For example, if I have a number `12.12`, how can I take the decimal in that number and replace it with a comma (`,`) so that the output would be `12,12`?

I tried this, but my app crashes because of it:

```
let number = 12.12

number.replace(/./g, ',');
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in order to localize the output? If so, mentioning that in the question may alter the answers you get and provide solutions that will allow some folks to see periods and others to see commas depending on how their computers are configured.

Comment: I'm using this to write a utility that replaces the incoming decimal from the backend with whatever thousands separator is associated with the current locale.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `replace` on a number, but you can use it on a string.
Convert your `number` to a string, and then call `replace`.
Also, the period (`.`) character has special meaning in regular expressions.  But you can just pass a plain string to `replace`.

```
const numberWithCommas = number.toString().replace('.', ',');
```

Comment: That will not work here as number is declared as a const.

Comment: @BarryKaye replace does not modify the original, it returns a new string which has the replaced value.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: @BarryKaye - yeah, it will. replace returns a new string, it doens't alter the existing one.

Comment: I will accept this answer, as I changed the number from a `const` to a `let`

Comment: Thank you @RalphDavidAbernathy, you do not need to change it from a `const`, it will work since neither `toString()` nor `replace()` modify the original variable.  You assign the result to a new variable, I have updated my answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var stringnumber = stringnumber.ToString();
var endresult = stringnumber.replace(".",",");
```

Comment: actually the `toString` method is a property of the number itself, so it would be `stringnumber = stringnumber.toString()` if you update that I'll upvote.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot change the value of a `const` in javascript.

Comment: yeah, you can. you just can't reassign it or use the same var name again in the same scope.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. How would you change the value of `number` at the Question?

Comment: you can't because its a primitive object, but in general, you *can* change the value of constants.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. _"you can change the value of constants"_ How? Will post a Question if you will post the Answer

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. That does not change the value of the `const`. That changes the value of a property of an object

Comment: @guest271314 The value of the `const` *is* the object, we changed the object, therefore we changed the value of the constant. MDN docs are clear: "The value of a constant cannot change *through re-assignment*, and it can't be redeclared"... exactly what I said in my first comment.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. No, that does not change that the value is an object. You changed a property of an object, not the object itself.

Comment: @guest271314 - Your argument is a futile attempt to avoid admitting you're incorrect. The property belong to the object, if you change the property, you change the object. There's a reason MDN stated it the way they did. If you change your hair color you can't say "I didn't cahnge my look, I just changed my hair color." Your hair color is a property of "your look." If I'm wrong then MDN is wrong. I'm not wrong.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. MDN has been wrong before. MDN is not the specification. You cannot change the plain object to a different value. A property of an object is not an object itself. Will post a Question to vet the inquiry.

Comment: @guest271314 - well, not this time. i've even proven it.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. You have not proven anything other than changing a _property_ of an object, not the _value_ itself. Am composing the Question where you can post your Answer.

Comment: @guest271314 - That would be an off-topic question. This is a matter of semantics, it has nothing to do with programming. If you change the property of anything you change the thing itself. If you're gonna ask you should ask on English Language Learners or Philosophy.. Be sure to post a link if you do decide to ask..

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. There is no such thing as a "stupid question". Nor is the inquiry based on english or philosophy. The inquiry is based on clarification of a technical document.

Comment: @guest271314 - No, it's not. It's based on your interpretation of the Enlish language used in that spec. Do you honestly believe either of us doesn't understand how a JS "constant" works? I'm pretty sure we both get it.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Could care less about the english language, which is an equivocal language to begin with. Technical writing is a different subject matter altogether.

Comment: @guest271314 i like candy

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48468210/how-to-replace-a-decimal-in-a-number-with-a-string#48468210

Comment: @guest271314 - wrong link, i think you meant to post this one.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48468819/what-is-can-the-value-of-a-variable-declared-using-const-be-changed

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Can you provide a definite Answer to the inquiry at the Question?

Comment: One of you guys should create a thread for this argument and post a link to it here.